# Ember-cli resolver

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project, and I want to create settings.js file placed in "app" folder, this is it:

```
export default {
    urls: {
        "companiesDepartmentsUrl": '/api/meta/get-departments',
        "savePartnersUrl": "/api/partners/save",
        "checkObjectId": "/api/objects/check-id",
        "objectsUrl": "/api/objects/find"
    }
};
```

Then in my view that is called "objects" (app/view/objects.js)
I try to import it this way:

```
import Settings from 'components/settings';
```

But I get error:

```
Error while processing route: objects.index Could not find module `front/views/app/models/menu-item` imported from `front/views/objects` Error: Could not find module `front/views/app/models/menu-item` imported from `front/views/objects`
```

What is wrong?

Thx a lot.

Comment: your code is complaining about something other than settings. Its complaining that `menu-item` doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import Settings from '<app-name>/settings';`.